# in POST call whatever request body is coming should be written in test file in java

Tags: java, websphere, commerce, hcl, wcs

I want to write POST call with plain/text data type consumption, which will read request and write to a file.  Using below code it write in file only one line not complete body. Any suggestion.

Handler class

```
@Path("store/{storeId}/datareceive")
@Description("Receives data from NiFi")
public class ElasticSearchDataRequestHandler extends AbstractConfigBasedClassicHandler {

    @Override
    public String getResourceName() {
        return RESOURCE_NAME;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML })
    public Response addNiFiDataToFile(@PathParam(STORE_ID) String storeId) throws Exception {
        final String methodName = "addNiFiDataToFile";
        LOGGER.debug(CLASSNAME, methodName);

        TypedProperty requestProperties = new TypedProperty();
        

        HashMap requstJson = new HashMap();
        
        System.out.println("request ---->" + request);

        requstJson.putAll(getMapFromRequest(request, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

        
        System.out.println("-----requstJson-----" + requstJson);
        requestProperties.put("requstJson", requstJson);
        return executeControllerCommandWithContext(storeId, ElasticSearchDataRequestCmd.NAME, requestProperties, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

Command

```
//private TypedProperty reqProp;
    private Object esData;
    //private TypedProperty respProperty;

    @Override
    public void setRequestProperties(TypedProperty reqProperties) throws ECException {
        if (reqProperties != null) {
            esData = reqProperties.get("requstJson");
            //System.out.println("reqProp =====" + reqProp);

        }
    }


public void performExecute() throws ECException {
    if (Objects.isNull(getResponseProperties()) || !getResponseProperties().containsKey(LogicConstants.CODE)) {
        addDataToFile();
    }
}

private void addDataToFile() throws ECException {
    System.out.println("----------------------Test Data--------------------------" + esData);
    
    TypedProperty respProperty = new TypedProperty();
    try {
        String TEXT_FILE = "C:" + File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "pawankumar" + File.separator + "Documents" + File.separator + getFileWithDate("product") + ".txt";
        // Use relative path for Unix systems
        System.out.println("TEXT_FILE ---------------> " + TEXT_FILE);
        Path textFilePath = Paths.get(TEXT_FILE);
        Files.createFile(textFilePath);
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(TEXT_FILE);
        System.out.println("===================" + esData);
        //myWriter.write(reqProp);
        myWriter.write(esData.toString());
        myWriter.close();

        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");

        
        respProperty.put(LogicConstants.CODE, String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.getCode()));
        respProperty.put(LogicConstants.MESSAGE, "Data added to file");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        respProperty.put(LogicConstants.CODE, String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.getCode()));
        respProperty.put(LogicConstants.MESSAGE, "Data added to file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*TypedProperty respProperty = new TypedProperty();
    respProperty.put(LogicConstants.CODE, String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.getCode()));
    respProperty.put(LogicConstants.MESSAGE, "User is successfully subscribed for newsletter.");*/

    setResponseProperties(respProperty);
}
```

To test
POST : http://localhost/wcs/resources/store/10151/datareceive

Body : plain/text

Request is as below:

```
{ "update": { "_id": "10151--1-10001-3074457345616676668", "_index": ".auth.10151.product.202206290450", "retry_on_conflict": 5, "_source": false } }
{ "doc": {"attachments":[{"identifier":"0AN4268__26346G_9cefa68b-1993-4294-bcd9-aafe0116c66f/0AN4268__26346G_090A","sequence":34.0,"name.raw":"Degree_090","description.raw":"","mime":"","rule":"PDP","id":"3074457345616669358","store":"10051","url":"/cdn-record-files-pi/ea504707-a6a6-4b6b-bb18-aaf701016153/9cefa68b-1993-4294-bcd9-aafe0116c66f/0AN4268__26346G_090A.png"},{"identifier":"0AN4268__26346G_d4279fe2-c87a-473b-909a-aafe0116d302/0AN4268__26346G_180A","sequence":35.0,"name.raw":"Degree_180","description.raw":"","mime":"","rule":"PDP","id":"3074457345616669359","store":"10051","url":"/cdn-record-files-pi/ea504707-a6a6-4b6b-bb18-aaf701016153/d4279fe2-c87a-473b-909a-aafe0116d302/0AN4268__26346G_180A.png"},{"identifier":"0AN4268__26346G_3f2f5455-651d-4558-9fc9-aafe0116be65/0AN4268__26346G_030A","sequence":32.0,"name.raw":"Degree_030","description.raw":"","mime":"","rule":"PDP","id":"3074457345616669360","store":"10051","url":"/cdn-record-files-pi/ea504707-a6a6-4b6b-bb18-aaf701016153/3f2f5455-651d-4558-9fc9-aafe0116be65/0AN4268__26346G_030A.png"},{"identifier":"0AN4268__26346G_3f2f5455-651d-4558-9fc9-aafe0116be65/0AN4268__26346G_030A_PLP","sequence":2.0,"name.raw":"Degree_030","description.raw":"","mime":"","rule":"PLP","id":"3074457345616669361","store":"10051","url":"/cdn-record-files-pi/ea504707-a6a6-4b6b-bb18-aaf701016153/3f2f5455-651d-4558-9fc9-aafe0116be65/0AN4268__26346G_030A.png"},{"identifier":"0AN4268__26346G_3f2f5455-651d-4558-9fc9-aafe0116be65/0AN4268__26346G_030A_Thumbnail","sequence":1.0,"name.raw":"Degree_030","description.raw":"","mime":"","rule":"Thumbnail","id":"3074457345616669362","store":"10051","url":"/cdn-record-files-pi/ea504707-a6a6-4b6b-bb18-aaf701016153/3f2f5455-651d-4558-9fc9-aafe0116be65/0AN4268__26346G_030A.png"},{"identifier":"0AN4268__26346G_9dd059c7-a0fc-434e-8594-aafe0116ba86/0AN4268__26346G_000A","sequence":33.0,"name.raw":"Degree_000","description.raw":"","mime":"","rule":"PDP","id":"3074457345616669363","store":"10051","url":"/cdn-record-files-pi/ea504707-a6a6-4b6b-bb18-aaf701016153/9dd059c7-a0fc-434e-8594-aafe0116ba86/0AN4268__26346G_000A.png"},{"identifier":"0AN4268__26346G_9dd059c7-a0fc-434e-8594-aafe0116ba86/0AN4268__26346G_000A_PLP","sequence":1.0,"name.raw":"Degree_000","description.raw":"","mime":"","rule":"PLP","id":"3074457345616669364","store":"10051","url":"/cdn-record-files-pi/ea504707-a6a6-4b6b-bb18-aaf701016153/9dd059c7-a0fc-434e-8594-aafe0116ba86/0AN4268__26346G_000A.png"}],"__meta":{"modified":"2022-06-29T04:51:36.939Z"}}, "doc_as_upsert": true }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Why tag with things like "commerce" and "websphere" – are those relevant? What have you tried already? How did it go?

Comment: Which java version are you using ?

Comment: I am using java8 version.

Comment: Why websphere --> I have created this POST call in HCL commerce only. After writing POST call when I am using it through postman, Only first line is getting added in file. Handler class

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what the question is, but.. I gather you're writing something to a file somewhere, it contains one line of output, and you're expecting there should be more than one line? Something like that? Looking at your code, there is only one place that writes to a file – `myWriter.write(esData.toString())` – but there is no definition of `esData` in the posted code. What is `esData`? Something to confirm: `esData` contains what you expect. If it has some other value, then that's your next step (track down why esData isn't correct).

Comment: esdata I took from setRequestProperty. What issue I see while reading content complete text is not read in request in handler. I have kept on sysout in handler which is not printing complete body sent from postman.